# Mapping a Scala future of a list

Tags: scala, future

I've a list of futures, which I'd like to transform one-by-one:

```
def foo(x: A): Future[B] = {...}
def mapFutures(xs: Future[List[A]]): Future[List[B]]
```

The function `mapFutures` should transform each element of the list using `foo`, and return a future of a list.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You say that you want to map a list of futures, but this is a future of a list. Which do you mean?

Comment: The latter - thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want like this (note I specified the types A and B as Int and String to make things easier to understand):

```
def foo(x: Int): String = x.toString 

def mapFutures(xs: Future[List[Int]]): Future[List[String]]  = {
  for(list <- xs) yield list map foo
}
```

Now if you wanted something more generic, then you could define `mapFutures` like so:

```
def mapFutures[A,B](xs: Future[List[A]], f:A => B): Future[List[B]]  = {
  for(list <- xs) yield list map f
}
```

And then it could be used like this:

```
val futs = Future(List(1,2,3))
val mappedFuts = mapFutures(futs, foo)
```

**EDIT**

Now, if foo returned a `Future`, you could do things like this:

```
def foo(x: Int): Future[String] = Future(x.toString) 

def mapFutures[A,B](xs: Future[List[A]], f:A => Future[B]): Future[List[B]]  = {
  for{
    list <- xs
    mapped <- Future.sequence(list map f)
  } yield mapped
}
```

Comment: Not quite - foo should return a Future[B], rather than just B.  In your case, this makes mapFutures[A, B] have return type Future[List[Future[B]]].

Comment: @thomson_matt, sorry I missed that part, I updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Just map the future:</strike>

```
val futureList = Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3))
val mappedList = futureList map { _ map { _ + 1 } }
```

To your specific example:

```
def foo(x: Int): String = x.toString
val fooList = fxs map { _ map foo }
```

---

EDIT (basically the same approach as cmbaxter; just without the for-comprehension).

For a future, you want to flatMap the sequence. Sequence converts a list of futures into a future of a list.

```
val fxs = Future(List(1, 2, 3))
def foo(x: Int): Future[String] = Future(x.toString)
val fooList = fxs flatMap { l => Future.sequence(l map foo) }
```

Comment: Not quite - foo should return a Future[String], rather than just String.

Answer (score 0):

You could use implicit class to add `flatMapSeq` extension method to `Future[List[A]]`.

```
implicit class RichFutureSeq[A](val future: Future[List[A]]) extends AnyVal {
  // def mapSeq[B](f: A => B): Future[List[B]] = future.map(_.map(f))
  def flatMapSeq[B](f: A => Future[B]): Future[List[B]] = future.flatMap(Future.traverse(_)(f))
}
```

then at your client, you could use it like this

```
// import the implicit if necessary
def foo(x: Int): Future[String] = Future.successful(x.toString)
val f : Future[List[Int]] = Future.successful(List(1, 2))
val fs: Future[List[String]] = f.flatMapSeq(foo)
def mapFutures(xs: Future[List[Int]])(f: Int => Future[String]): Future[List[String]] = xs.flatMapSeq(f)
```